# Действия, входящие в backend

Tags: php, база-данных, сервер, клиент-сервер, backend

Нашел в интернете https://skillbox.ru/media/code/frontend_i_backend_razrabotka/ :

> Backend-разработка — это набор аппаратно-программных средств, при помощи которых реализована логика работы сайта. Попросту говоря, это то, что скрыто от глаз пользователя и происходит вне его браузера и компьютера. 
>   Например, когда вы вводите запрос на странице поисковика и жмёте клавишу Enter, frontend заканчивается и начинается backend. Ваш запрос отправляется на сервер Google или «Яндекса», где расположены алгоритмы поиска. Именно там случается всё «волшебство». Как только на мониторе появилась информация, которую вы искали, — вновь происходит возвращение в зону frontend.

Также нашел https://tproger.ru/translations/backend-web-development/ . Из всего приведенного я понял, что в backend входят следующие вещи:

1. Обработка запросов, переданных в поисковую строку;
2. Работа с базами данных;
3. Работа с почтовыми рассылками

Поскольку я новичок, прошу привести еще действия, входящие в backend (серверной части), поскольку я привел только 3 вещи.

Comment: Вообще можно разделить так: фронт - просто очень примитивная и глупая сторона, которая может только показывать данные, производить предварительную обработку (для отправки на сервер) данных в запросах, отправлять и получать запросы. А вот абсолютно всю обработку делает сервер (сюда входят различные CRUD операции, аналитика, конфигурация, и различные операции-расчеты и т д). Но т к в данный момент начинают развиваться клиентские машины - то некоторую часть возлагают на фронт (на свой страх и риск)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделение FrontEnd-BackEnd не в том, **какие** где действия совершаются, а в том **где** какие-то действия совершаются.

Всё вами перечисленное можно делать и на FrontEnd, исполняя в браузере. Если вам нужен совсем полный список того, что можно делать на стороне сервера, то можете смело включать туда вообще всё. Клиенту можно оставить только обязанность зажечь нужным цветом пиксели на экране.

---

Однако, есть некоторый набор лучших практик, согласно которым перечисленное вами принято исполнять на стороне сервера.

1. Первый аргумент в пользу выноса части логики на сервер - возможность защитить данные. Например логин/пароль к базе данных или почтовому сервису, расчёт траектории пули в игре, алгоритм вычисления выдачи на поисковый запрос.
2. Второй аргумент - быстродействие. Тот же расчёт поисковой выдачи на запрос требует хранения петабайт (или больше) данных и десятков/сотен/тысяч гигабайт оперативной памяти и мощных процессоров. Если всё это будет на стороне клиента (браузере) потребуются часы/дни для простого запроса на слабом компьютере.

Answer (score 1):

Фронтенд и бекенд означают ровно то, что означают: спереди и сзади.

1. Классическое современное и ходовое понимание таковое, что фронтенд - браузерная история, а бекенд - серверная.

Но есть и некоторые др практики использования этих слов в обиходе.

2. Например Nginx при использовании с сервером Apache говорят "на фронте у нас Nginx", тк он первым обрабатывает запросы (стоит спереди) и отдает статику, то что не нужно пропускать через более глубокую (которая позади (at back)) логику.
3. Еще один пример. Некий банковский софт, обрабатывающий сложную логику выдачи кредита, пишется на java, а для "фронта", для информации, которую выводит система есть "фронтенд" на php, ruby, который просто работает с этим тяжелым бекендом и выводит только то, что нужно, при чем в этой команде может быть вой фронтендер, который уже в понимании 1 пункта пишет браузерное отображение на JS :)
4. Фронтенд-команда в некоторых компаниях - менеджеры, бекенд - повара.

**Итого:** Абстрактные понятия тянут за собой разнообразные смысл в угоду относительных обстоятельств и ситуаций. Фронт - спереди, бек - сзади, этого достаточно :)